# How to restrict the panning movement in Three.js without modifying OrbitControl.js?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to restrict the panning movement since the scene is a skybox, I don't want to pan left/right too much. Currently what I am doing is just simply modifying the OrbitControl.js to restrict the panning action:

```
            const right_max = 210;
            const left_min = -210;

            //restrict the movement
            if(position.x >right_max && deltaX <0 ){
                return;
            }
            if(position.x <-left_min && deltaX >0){
                return;
            }
```

But I don't like the way it is, since it breaks the source file, may cause issues when you publish the project (I installed three.js as npm package).
Is there any way you can do this out of box and don't change the source file ? Something like this:

```
 orbitControl.addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
       if( camera.position.x > right_max){
           // stop panning to right 
       }
       ...
 })
```

Comment: Try https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-limit-pan-in-orbitcontrols-for-orthographiccamera/9061

Comment: It works! @WestLangley Thanks!

Comment: Please answer and accept your own question and show your solution.

Answer (score 1):

As inspried by the post from [three.js forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-limit-pan-in-orbitcontrols-for-orthographiccamera/9061), we can restrict the panning in this way (posted by [Elias Hasle](https://discourse.threejs.org/u/eliashasle/summary)):

```
const minPan = new Vector3(-210,0,-80);
const maxPan = new Vector3(210,0,100);
const _v = new Vector3(); 

const orbitControl = addOrbitControl();
orbitControl.addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
    _v.copy(orbitControl.target);
    orbitControl.target.clamp(minPan,maxPan);
    _v.sub(orbitControl.target);
    camera.position.sub(_v);
})
```

Note that the camera would drift a little bit due to clamping, we move the camera accordingly to avoid it.